# Why does my war take so much space when deployed on GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

When I compile my GAE/GWT (Java) project (compiling all 6 permutations), the whole WAR folder has a weight of 93.9 Mo on my computer (extended Mac OS journaled). When deployed on GAE, the Admin console (Quota Details page) shows that my app takes 18% of the free quota. Meaning 180Mb. How is this possible ? I am missing something ? Is google using a filesystem with big blocks ?? How to optimize the usage of the available storage space ? I'm already JARing my 'classes' folder, but the gain (in terms of space...) is not relevant.

The biggest problem (from my point of view) is that my own GWT + server side code + 'external' library (PDFJet) is taking a tiny 1.9Mb. All the rest (>91Mb) is taken by appengine's and datanucleus own libraries. Why do we need to include those in the deployment ? They are used by everyone. I think it would be better for all of us when these would be centrally and automatically deployed. I don't get it.

Any advices or comments on this ?

Comment: How many versions do you have uploaded onto GAE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to ensure GWT post compilation output is tuned towards **production deployment** and in your case for **"cloud"** .

### Ensure for Production deployment

1) GWT Compiler flag for STYLE IS OBF

2) GWT Compilation turns off stack trace emulator feature. In .gwt.xml

```
<set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="strip" />
```

### Ensure for Cloud deployment

1) GWT Compiler flag for **extra** and **deploy** is used to direct away mostly deployment redundant files away from WAR file. I am guessing you have massive folder called deploy in your WEB-INF.

**Edit** -

1) Reference to GWT Compiler options - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging

2) Reference to Google Group discussion - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/-WtEfDvUI4g

Comment: You are right, the deploy folder is relatively big. Can you please provide a link with the GWT compiler docs ? It looks that we have here a lot of options wich I never heard about before.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Updated with link in the answer. You need trade off between trying to optimize build time performance, runtime performance, bandwidth performance, deploy size performance and developer debugging features in GWT.